# Adding UINavigationController to View Other Than Main View

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'd like to add a UINavigationController to my app info view (NOT to my main view). I've watched/read a number of tutorials showing how to add it to the main window through the AppDelegate using IB. In my case, I only want it to appear when a user presses the info button and is brought to the infoView. Here is how I switch to the infoView within my MainViewController:

```
- (IBAction)infoButtonPress:(id)sender
{
    // Create pointer to instance of InfoViewController
    InfoViewController *infoView = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    // Add view switching animation
    infoView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    // Change view using animation
    [self presentModalViewController:infoView animated:YES];    
}
```

At this point the infoView is displayed and I would like THIS to be the RootView of the UINavigationController. I have tried adding the line:

```
UINavigationController *infoNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                                             initWithRootViewController:infoView];
```

after creating an instance of InfoViewController, but the app crashes. Is it possible to add UINavigationController to views other than the main view?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the crash log say? That line should be fine. Then you should present the infoNavController as the modal view controller instead of presenting the infoView itself.

Comment: Ohh.. so I change infoView in the second and third lines to infoNavController. That does work, thanks. Doing it this way, do I have to edit the NavigationBar programmatically? Or can I still use the IB?

Comment: Programmatically will be easiest in this scenario, unless you are going to load the entire navigation controller from a XIB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close with your implementation. Try it in this order.

```
InfoViewController *infoView = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *infoNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                                             initWithRootViewController:infoView];
[infoView release]; // skip this if using ARC
infoView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:infoNavController animated:YES];
```

**UPDATE**

To kill this modal, you will have to add your buttons to the main modal view.

```
InfoViewController.m

-(void)cancel:(id)sender {
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Cancel"
                                     style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target: self
                                    action: @selector(cancel:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
    [cancelButton release];
}
```

Comment: Ok. Now because this UINavigationController is being created in my MainViewController, how can I use it to say `[infoNavController pushViewController:AboutViewController];` to "slide" to the About view from my Info view inside InfoViewController?

Comment: This will just put your infoView inside a navigationView. If you want to push other views, you will need to push them seperately or from within your navigationView you just created. If you want the next view to slide over from the nav view, just alloc/init your new view and push, just like your comment.

Comment: Sorry, if you are going to push your new view onto the stack, you would do it from your rootViewController, which from this question would be InfoViewController. it should work ok.

Comment: I guess I am confused because the UINavigationController is created in MainViewController, so do I have to create ANOTHER UINavigationController in InfoViewController to handle the view pushing? If so, what was the point of creating one in Main?

Comment: This answer is creating a modal view with nav controller. The modal nav is not connected to your mainView, just the modal. When you dismiss the modal, everything goes away leaving your mainView. If you need more than that, you will have to adjust your question or ask another.

Comment: My problem is once I transition to the modal (leaving mainView), I can get my info view with the nav bar on top, but aside from giving it a title.. it has no functionality. I can't seem to set a backBarButton for some reason, and I also can't seem to push FROM infoView TO aboutView. I've tried so many things and I am just in a tailspin now.

Comment: See edits. I added the functionality to add to add the cancel button to your modal. Hope this helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6707/discussion-between-kevin-ta-and-bill-brasky)